# BLOB data returned in MySQL using AES_DECRYPT with ORDER clause

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, blob, aes

I'm creating a system in which users can store messages via PHP with a MySQL database, and I am using the MySQL AES_ENCRYPT function to encrypt the contents of these messages.

Here is my *posts* table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` varbinary(1000) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `replyto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `replyto` (`replyto`),
  KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


ALTER TABLE `posts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`replyto`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And my *users* table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

The AES encryption key I'm using for the message body is a SHA-512-hashed concatenation between a prefix and suffix string, and the posting user's GUID in the middle. Thus, I have the following SQL query to select the most recent messages:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`posts`.`body`, SHA2(CONCAT('prefix',(`users`.`guid`),'suffix'),512)) AS 'realbody'
FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user` = `users`.`id` 
ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC
```

Unfortunately, this does not return the decrypted messages, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/N1B1iqR.png]

Instead, I'm getting this BLOB data. However, if I remove the ORDER BY clause from the query:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`posts`.`body`, SHA2(CONCAT('prefix',(`users`.`guid`),'suffix'),512)) AS 'realbody'
FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user` = `users`.`id`
```

Then suddenly, it works:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6ArQPHN.png]

I really don't know what could be causing this. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATED** `CAST` it to `CHAR`

```
SELECT `posts`.*, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(`posts`.`body`,SHA2(CONCAT('prefix',`users`.`guid`,'suffix'),512)) AS CHAR) as 'realbody'
  FROM `posts` JOIN `users` 
    ON `posts`.`user` = `users`.`id`
 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC
```

Sample output:

```
 | ID | USER | ... | REALBODY |
 ---...------------------------
 |  2 |    2 | ... |   Post 2 |
 |  1 |    1 | ... |   Post 1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ccd9a/9)** demo

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately I still have the same issue.

Comment: @WilliamThomas can you create a sqlfiddle with a few rows of sample data?

Comment: I just did but unfortunately it looks like binary data is being returned no matter what: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ccd9a/4/0

Comment: Oh wow, I should have tried that. Worked beautifully, thanks!