# AES_DECRYPT Getting the value from a blob in typescript

Tags: mysql, typescript, blob, aes, angular5

Coding an Angular 5/typescript client calling a node.js webserver talking to a MySQL DB. Had a successfully working call for names:

```
SELECT *
FROM stories JOIN users
ON stories.author_id=users.id
WHERE stories.story_id = 1;
```

If I need to encrypt the last names of authors at a field level in the DB, I could use AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT. This changes the call to this. I used dlname here to distinguish the decrypted value from the lname field.

```
SELECT *, AES_DECRYPT(lname, UNHEX(SHA2('some phrase',512))) AS dlname
FROM stories JOIN users
ON stories.author_id=users.id
WHERE stories.story_id = 1;
```

This works in dev environment using phpMyAdmin, the dlname is fine on the return and shows as text. But when pushed to a prod env with MySQL and call it, the typescript (Angular 5 client) shows dlname as a blob [object Object]. I checked it with MySQL Workbench and it also shows it as a blob, which I can right-click on and then "Open value in viewer" and I see the last name just fine.

My question is, how do I write the typescript code to get the actual lname value out of the blob? The pertinent lines of code are...

```
this.http.get<StoryRes>(sRootURI + '/getStory/' + sDocID)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.sAuthor = data[0].fname + ' ' + data[0].dlname;
```

In this case, the dlname shows in the console as [object Object].

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out from some help found in [BLOB data returned in MySQL using AES_DECRYPT with ORDER clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072379/blob-data-returned-in-mysql-using-aes-decrypt-with-order-clause). Add a CAST(... AS CHAR) around your AES_DECRYPT function...

```
SELECT *, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(lname, UNHEX(SHA2('some phrase',512))) AS CHAR) as dlname...
```

On the client side, just make sure to call the new field name dlname instead of the actual name lname. Nothing additional is needed on the client side, will come through as text, as expected.